# FFMPEG - Scrambled Output converting from VOB with ffmpeg

Tags: c#, video, ffmpeg, vob

I've concatenated a series of VOB files from a DVD into a single VOB file and I am trying to convert it to MP4 or other similar format.  I see a lot of errors when converting and the output appears scrambled.

```
>ffmpeg.exe" -i file.vob -sameq file.mp4
FFmpeg version git-N-29181-ga304071, Copyright (c) 2000-2011 the FFmpeg develope
rs
  built on Apr 18 2011 21:24:03 with gcc 4.5.2
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --ena
ble-memalign-hack --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-frei0r --enable-libo
pencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --
enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger
 --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enabl
e-libx264 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-zlib --cross-prefix=i686-w6
4-mingw32- --target-os=mingw32 --arch=x86_32 --extra-cflags=-I/home/kyle/softwar
e/ffmpeg/external-libraries/win32/include --extra-ldflags=-L/home/kyle/software/
ffmpeg/external-libraries/win32/lib --pkg-config=pkg-config
  libavutil    50. 40. 1 / 50. 40. 1
  libavcodec   52.120. 0 / 52.120. 0
  libavformat  52.108. 0 / 52.108. 0
  libavdevice  52.  4. 0 / 52.  4. 0
  libavfilter   1. 79. 0 /  1. 79. 0
  libswscale    0. 13. 0 /  0. 13. 0
[mpeg2video @ 01751A90] ac-tex damaged at 5 16
[mpeg2video @ 01751A90] invalid mb type in I Frame at 0 1
[mpeg2video @ 01751A90] invalid mb type in I Frame at 0 2
[mpeg2video @ 01751A90] invalid mb type in I Frame at 0 3
[mpeg2video @ 01751A90] invalid mb type in I Frame at 0 4

[...]
```

I'm guessing this is CSS scrambling and I need to do some sort of DeCSS.  Does FFMpeg have an option for this?  Cringe if you'd like, but is there C# source to achieve this?

My end goal is really just to get some DVDs that I own onto my media server.  I've tried a few demo-ware products with limited success including Acala DVD Ripper, Click to Disk, AVIDemux to name a few.  I even paid for a couple of them to get the full version, but Acala only works for about half of my DVDs and Click to Disk can decode the VOB, but I need to use FFMpeg to convert.  I'd like to have it all in one app that works and I am willing to write some code for it.

Comment: `git-N-29181-ga304071` is ancient. `ffmpeg` can not decode CSS. How did you create the vob file? Does anything play the vob file normally? Do not use [`-sameq`: it does not mean "same quality"](http://superuser.com/a/478550/110524).

Comment: To create the VOB I just copied the files from the DVD directly.  After writing this post I tried playing the VOB directly, and like you suggest, it is also scrambled.  Are there utilities for descrambling the VOB?

Comment: You can try `vobcopy` (or maybe Handbrake?).

Comment: Handbrake worked great for me.  Specifically HandBrakeCLI.exe.  I had to grab a DLL from another product as described here: http://www.howtogeek.com/102886/how-to-decrypt-dvds-with-hardbrake-so-you-can-rip-them/